# how Wep API works together with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I developed a website using ASP.NET MVC5 with Entity Framework and Microsoft Identity. Now I need to add Web API to this project for mobile app development using RESTful architecture. My questions are:

1. Does Api controller and Mvc controller shares the same request pipeline?
2. Can I separately implement the Cookie based authentication for website and the Token based authentication for Api?
3. If I deploy the website on IIS, does this mean Web Api will also be automatically hosted by IIS?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your questions:

1. No, they using different pipeline. For MVC check this [document](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application)
   and for WebAPI [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36476). Basically MVC will use same pipeline
   as previous ASP.NET implementations and Web API using OWIN based
   model, however since you host it on IIS request still will go
   through modules and etc., but it's better not to relay on them. MVC
   and Web API pipelines merged in ASP.NET 5, where all of them uses
   OWIN
2. Yes, it's up to you how authorization will be implemented. You can
   even separate authorization for different WebAPI controllers: [just
   create different authorization filters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)
3. Yes, it will be configured with OWIN implementation, but hosted on
   IIS